# Python + Selenium краш при except

Tags: python, selenium

Есть приложение, в котором мне нужно выполнить проверку на наличие объекта на странице с id messageBoxInLine. При успешном нахождении объекта, никаких проблем не возникает, но как-только элемент пропадает со страницы и выполняется проверка, приложение просто зависает

```
def msgbox():
  try:
    msgbox = browser.find_element_by_css_selector('#messageBoxInline').text
  except NoSuchElementException:
    msgbox_none = 'Таблички нет'
    return msgbox_none
return msgbox
```

Answer (score 0):

Вот так должно работать

```
def msgbox():
  try:
      msgbox = browser.find_element_by_css_selector('#messageBoxInline').text
      return msgbox
  except NoSuchElementException:
      return 'Таблички нет'
```